# First letter capitalization for EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm working on a little personal todo list app and so far everything has been working quite well. There is one little quirk I'd like to figure out. Whenever I go to add a new item, I have a Dialog with an EditText view showing inside. When I select the EditText view, the keyboard comes up to enter text, as it should. In most applications, the default seems to be that the shift key is held for the first letter... although it does not do this for my view. There has to be a simple way to fix, but I've searched the reference repeatedly and cannot find it. I'm thinking there has to be an xml attribute for the reference loaded by the Adapter, but I can't find out what it is.

Answer (score 877, accepted):

Statically (i.e. in your layout XML file): set `android:inputType="textCapSentences"` on your `EditText`.

Programmatically: you have to include `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT` in the `InputType` of the `EditText`, e.g.

```
EditText editor = new EditText(this); 
editor.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
```

> Can be combined with text and its variations to request capitalization of the first character of every sentence.

[- Google Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType)

Comment: testEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS);   

or android:inputType="textCapSentences" will only work If your device keyboard Auto Capitalize Setting enabled.

Comment: Why does enabling this cause my `android:lines="7"` to no longer show 7 lines (it now defaults back to 1 line)

Comment: estEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS); or android:inputType="textCapSentences" will only work If your device keyboard Auto Capitalize Setting enabled. **What is the alternative for this, programmtically ?**

Comment: @JamesWierzba I will refer here Shivang answer as response for multi-line support. Add  android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"

Comment: Use android:inputType="text|textMultiLine|textCapSentences" to allow multiple lines text

Answer (score 90):

Just use `android:inputType="textCapWords"` in your EditText element.

For example:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtName"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:inputType="textCapWords"
    android:textColorHint="#aaa"
    android:hint="Name Surname"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

Refer to the following link for reference:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType

Comment: It is good practice to mark the code in code element instead make it bold.

Comment: This answer doesn't really help OP's question. This will capitalize the first character for each **word**, not the first character of the input text (which is assumed as a sentence). While this may probably help the others, the correct answer is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 52):

Apply following line in your EditText in XML.

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
```

It will also allow multi-line support.

Comment: That should be an accepted answer, as this is the only solution which won't collapse EditText into single-line

Answer (score 33):

```
testEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS);
```

or `android:inputType="textCapSentences"` will only work If your device keyboard Auto Capitalize Setting enabled.

Comment: Thanks, I was stuck because I just disabled device keyboard Auto Capitalize Setting

Answer (score 25):

I encountered the same problem, just sharing what I found out. Might help you and others...

Try this on your layout.add the line below in your `EditText`.

```
android:inputType="textCapWords|textCapSentences"
```

works fine on me.. hope it works also on you...

Answer (score 15):

If you want capital first letter in every word then use `android:inputType="textCapWords"`

For Better understanding

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt_description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textCapWords"/>
```

And if you capital word for every sentence  then use it .
`android:inputType="textCapSentences"` this line in your xml. I mean in your EditText.

For Better understanding

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt_description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences"/>
```

Answer (score 12):

To capitalize, you can do the following with edit text:

To make first letter capital **of every word**:

```
android:inputType="textCapWords"
```

To make first letter capital **of every sentence**:

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences"
```

To make **every letter** capital:

```
android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
```

But this will only make changes to keyboard and user can change the mode to write letter in small case.

So this approach is not much appreciated if you really want the data in capitalize format, add following class first:

```
public class CapitalizeFirstLetter {
    public static String capitaliseName(String name) {
        String collect[] = name.split(" ");
        String returnName = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < collect.length; i++) {
            collect[i] = collect[i].trim().toLowerCase();
            if (collect[i].isEmpty() == false) {
                returnName = returnName + collect[i].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + collect[i].substring(1) + " ";
            }
        }
        return returnName.trim();
    }
    public static String capitaliseOnlyFirstLetter(String data)
    {
        return data.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+data.substring(1);
    }
}
```

And then,

Now to capitalize every word:

```
CapitalizeFirstLetter.capitaliseName(name);
```

To capitalize only first word:

```
CapitalizeFirstLetter.capitaliseOnlyFirstLetter(data);
```

Answer (score 8):

For Capitalisation in EditText you can choose the below two input types:

> 1. android:inputType="textCapSentences"
> 2. android:inputType="textCapWords"

**textCapSentences**
This will let the first letter of the first word as Capital in every sentence.

**textCapWords**
This will let the first letter of every word as Capital.

If you want both the attributes just use | sign with both the attributes

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences|textCapWords"
```

Answer (score 6):

I can assure you both the answers will make first letter capital and will not make edittext single line.

If you want to do it in XMl below is the code

```
android:inputType="textCapWords|textCapSentences"
```

If want to do it in activity/fragment etc below is the code

```
momentTextView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE)
```

PS: If you are having nay other property also you can easily add it with a pipe "|" symbol, just make sure there is no space in xml between the attribute properties

Answer (score 6):

**In your layout XML file :**

- set `android:inputType="textCapSentences"`
- On your `EditText` to have first alphabet of the first word of each sentence as capital
- Or `android:inputType="textCapWords"` on your EditText to have first alphabet of each word as capital

Answer (score 3):

Set input type in XML as well as in JAVA file like this,

In XML,

> android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"

It will also allow **multiline** and in JAVA file,

```
edittext.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
```

make sure your keyboard's **Auto-Capitalization** setting is **Enabled**.

Answer (score 3):

**use this code to only First letter capitalization for EditText**

MainActivity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:tag="true">
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
EditText et = findViewById(R.id.et);
        et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2)
            {
                if (et.getText().toString().length() == 1 && et.getTag().toString().equals("true"))
                {
                    et.setTag("false");
                    et.setText(et.getText().toString().toUpperCase());
                    et.setSelection(et.getText().toString().length());
                }
                if(et.getText().toString().length() == 0)
                {
                    et.setTag("true");
                }
            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This Code, it will capitalize first character of all words.

**- set addTextChangedListener for EditText view**

edt_text.addTextChangedListener(watcher);

**- Add TextWatcher**

```
TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
    int mStart = 0;

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        mStart = start + count;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String input = s.toString();
        String capitalizedText;
        if (input.length() < 1)
            capitalizedText = input;
        else if (input.length() > 1 && input.contains(" ")) {
            String fstr = input.substring(0, input.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
            if (fstr.length() == input.length()) {
                capitalizedText = fstr;
            } else {
                String sstr = input.substring(input.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
                sstr = sstr.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + sstr.substring(1);
                capitalizedText = fstr + sstr;
            }
        } else
            capitalizedText = input.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + input.substring(1);

        if (!capitalizedText.equals(edt_text.getText().toString())) {
            edt_text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    edt_text.setSelection(mStart);
                    edt_text.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                }
            });
            edt_text.setText(capitalizedText);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

i founded and my solution :
you have 2 way to resolve it 
in java :

```
 testEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT 
 | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS);
```

and xml :

```
 <EditText
android:id="@+id/mytxt"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:inputType="textCapWords"
android:textSize="12sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Earlier it used to be `android:capitalize="words"`, which is now deprecated. The recommended alternative is to use `android:inputType="textCapWords"`

Please note that this will only work if your device keyboard Auto Capitalize Setting enabled.

To do this programatically, use the following method:

`setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS);`

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically

```
TextView firstline = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.firstline);
firstline.setAllCaps(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are writing styles in styles.xml then

**remove android:inputType** property and add below lines

```
<item name="android:capitalize">words</item>
```