# How to auto-capitalize an EditText inside an AlertDalog?

Tags: android

I want to show an AlertDialog containing an EditText that auomtically capitalizes words.

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403632/android-show-soft-keyboard-automatically-when-focus-is-on-an-edittext) and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808705/first-letter-capitalization-for-edittext), I managed to get the AlertDialog show the keyboard automatically when the dialog is shown, and also capitalize the first letter when the user clicks on the `EditText`. But until the user clicks, the keyboard shows in lowercase mode.

How can I make the keyboard open automatically in upper-case (auto-capitalize words) mode?

My relevant code is as follows:

```
    input = new EditText(context);
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS);

    dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

Also tried to `requestFocus()` in the dialog's `onShowListener` but it didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use the following code after your AlertDialog declaration.

```js
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK);

final EditText edittext = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
// Just use it here, there is much more options in the link below
edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
```

[Look for other options here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html)

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that worked for me was to avoid using `setMessage()`, and adding the message into my own view instead (using `setView()`).