# How to Initial keyboard start with Uppercase letter and when press dot again start with Uppercase letter in soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have Tried these InputType but my issue not solve. My XML you can see. Please any suggestion.I extended softkeyboard class
public class SoftKeyboard extends InputMethodService implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener, SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener { –
Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LatinKeyboardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/urduSimple"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:alpha="1"
android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
android:inputType="textCapSentences"
android:keyBackground="@drawable/transparent_key_shape"
android:keyPreviewLayout="@layout/key_preview"
android:keyPreviewOffset="-4dp"
android:keyTextColor="@color/White"
android:paddingTop="4dp"
android:keyTextSize="28dp"
android:shadowRadius="0.0"
 android:popupLayout="@layout/keyboard_popup_layout">
 </LatinKeyboardView>
 Java:
            case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT:
            EditText editor = new EditText(this);
            editor.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | 
            InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
```

Comment: Explain what you want to achieve in steps .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [First letter capitalization for EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808705/first-letter-capitalization-for-edittext)

Comment: Hy ADM i want to achieve when i start typing in my custom keyboard then initial alphabet should be uppercase letter.

Comment: did you tried ?
`android:inputType="textCapSentences"`

Comment: Hy Mashuk Khan i have tried but not this answer solve my issue.

Comment: Yes Benjith binja i tried.

Comment: Please go through the documentation
[link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType)

Answer (score 2):

textCapSentences will work if user do not manually change the Softkeyboard to lower case. A normaly sentence ends with dot and a space after it.So it will perfectly work for this formate.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

If user manually change the Keyboard then you should use a **TextWatcher** to formate the text again in sentence case.

Comment: thanks ADM i tried this solution but not solve my problem.

Comment: In which device you are testing ? on what api level. Although i think this is not Api level dependent thing.

Comment: android version 4.4.2 Api Level 19

Comment: I am afraid that can be an issue. Kitkat and Kitkat MR  are differ in some functions from the other android versions . So pls test with other api device other then Kitkat and KitkatMR.

Comment: thank you so much ADM for suggestion i tried on different device but still not solve.

Comment: Do not post here . Edit the question

Comment: LatinKeyboardView extend EditText isn't it ?

Comment: You have customized the SoftKeyboard . You should have put this code in question at first place.

Comment: I have just tested it with  android:inputType="textCapSentences" in edit text after removing  key attributes and popuplayout . Its working as  expected .